# Update Server time stamp - firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I am new to using firestore and would greatly appreciate an answer.

I am updating the documents in my firestore with a timestamp. Will that timestamp represent the time that document was originally created, or does the timestamp represent the time that i updated it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just depends on whether you update that field in particular or not.

If you update the field containing the timestamp on each write then it will represent that update time.
You don't mention it but if you work with AngularFire, you can make sure the timestamp gets updated on each write if your update is something like this:

```
.doc('user/' + user.id).update({
      someValue: "someValue",
      date: firebase.default.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
    })
```

Comment: I was not aware firestore did not add data chronologically, so I am trying to add a timestamp to all the documents, however, they did not previously have a timestamp field, so if i update each document to have a timestamp, that would mean each document would have the timestamp of the time i updated it rather than the time the document was orignaly sent to the database,  is that understanding correct?

Comment: Your understanding is correct: when you write the `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` value, it takes on the current time on the server. So this does not allow you to write the date the document was created.